# Word VBA: Disable privacy option in Trust Center

Tags: vba, ms-word

Within Word 2010's Trust Center's Privacy Options is the *Remove personal information from file properties on save* check box. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Using Word VBA, I would like to be able to be able to detect for the enabled/disabled state of this setting and then, if enabled, disable it. However, I have not been able to find within the Word 2010 Object Model any way to directly access this setting.

I am able to remove personal information (equivalent to enabling the option) using this method:

```
ActiveDocument.RemoveDocumentInformation (wdRDIDocumentProperties)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot detect the Boolean value for the setting nor disable it with VBA.

Lastly, I also explored the `BuiltInDocumentProperties` property, but there was no access via the constants found in the Object Model.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`activedocument.RemovePersonalInformation=true` sets the word option to remove the information

`CurrentSetting=activedocument.RemovePersonalInformation` to save the setting for later

This was tested on word 2007.

Comment: Thanks so much. My eyes must have skipped over RemovePersonalInformation a thousand times. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It also works with Office 365, e.g.

*activedocument.RemovePersonalInformation = False*

In this case, the option to re-enable removing the personal info is grayed out via the menu (File->Options->Trust Center->Privacy options). Setting it to *True* via code re-enables and ungrays the option via the menu.